# CSV file is being created larger than the size of my original data in python/pycharm?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, bigdata

I am trying to load a set of around 10000 images as numpy arrays into a CSV file to train a model. My problem is that my original data is of 40 MB while the csv that is created is of 3 GB which i cannot figure out why. ideally it should be less than the data. i am working on ubuntu 16.04 with pycharm using python 3 and using Libre Office Calc to open CSV's. i cannot paste the snippet of CSV because the numpy array in only one row is too large and it exceeds the body limit for this question. Here is my code:

**Csv creation code**

```
import csv
from utils import extract_images_from_path

path_csv_out =  "/home/rehan/countries/influencer.csv"
image_path = "/home/rehan/countries/"
csv_out = open(path_csv_out, 'w', newline="")

writer = csv.writer(csv_out, delimiter=';')
row = ["image", "country", "gender", "age", "ethnicity", "image_path"]
writer.writerow(row)
for row in extract_images_from_path(image_path, with_folder_meta=True, exclude="sdfsdfsdgdfgdfg", include="cropped_colored",
                                    start_counter=0, end_counter=125440, colored_version=True):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

**function for extracting images from folder**

```
def extract_images_from_path(path, extension=".jpg", exclude="cropped", include="", start_counter=0, end_counter=10000,
                             with_folder_meta=False, colored_version=True, seperator="/"):
    location_images = []
    counter = 0
    age = 1
    gender = 'guys'
    country = 'germany'
    ethnicity = 0
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
        if with_folder_meta:
            dirpath = str(dirpath).replace("\\", "/")
            current_folder = dirpath.rsplit(seperator, 1)[1]
            print(current_folder)
            if current_folder==dirpath.rsplit('/')[4]:
                country=current_folder
            try:
                age = int(current_folder)
            except ValueError as e:
                if "guys" in current_folder:
                    gender = 1 if current_folder == "guys" else 0
                else:
                    gender = 0
                    if "france" in country:
                        ethnicity = 1
                    else:
                        ethnicity = 0
        for file in filenames:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                counter += 1
                if not start_counter <= counter <= end_counter:
                    continue
                image_path = str(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
                image_path = str(image_path).replace("\\", "/")
                image = cv2.imread(image_path)
                height, width, pixel = image.shape
                # test_convert = np.fromstring(image.tostring(), image.dtype).reshape(52,52,3)
                image = image.reshape(height*width*pixel)
                # image = image.astype('float32')
                # image = np.multiply(image, 1.0 / 255.0)
                # print (image)
                image = image.tolist()
                # print (np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3))
                # image = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3).tostring()
                # image = pickle.dumps(image, protocol=0)
                if not with_folder_meta:
                    result_row = image
                else:
                    result_row = [image, country, gender, age, ethnicity, image_path]
                yield result_row
                if counter % 100 == 0:
                    print(counter)
        if counter > end_counter:
            break
```

Comment: are the images by any chance jpgs?

Comment: @Eumel yes they are.

Comment: jpgs are really compressed so if you write pixel for pixel into a file its a lot bigger than a compressed image

Comment: @Eumel ok ok. but then what could be a better solution to keep the CSV size under control as i want to train models using later and such large size will slow down my PC.?

Comment: depending on the quality you need the pictures if you can try reducing the size by downsampling (done by applying a gaussblur and the making 1 pixel from 4). If you are training a model haven a smaller picture generally isnt affecting it a lot, so that might be an option.

Comment: I think 3GB is not a Big Data. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data

Comment: @VadimKotov thats arguing about semantics and not actually helpful ;) Then again 3 GB is not actually that big and normally not your bottleneck.

Comment: @Eumel yeah, I know, just a hint for Rehan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems like having a 3Gb file is to be expected given your data and how you are storing it:

So you are starting with compressed JPEG images, **jpeg with high quality (Q=50) have a compression ratio of about 15** [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Effects_of_JPEG_compression) (it's very variable depending on the content of the picture but we're only doing back-of-the-envelope calculation here).

Assuming your pictures are in the standard 8-bit per color format, your images are now arrays of 8-bit values, those value are ranging between 0 and 256 so to write down every number in a text file you will need about **3 characters per number**.

If you are writing those character in a CSV format you will most likely have one coma and one space after each number, so lets say in total you will get about **5 characters per number** with each character weighting 1 byte (assuming ASCII encoding).

Combining all that we get:

`total bytes of uncompressed data = 40Mb*15  = 600Mb`

`total characters needed to write those bytes as text in a CSV = 600Mb*5 = 3G`

`expected file size in ASCII encoding = 3G * 1b = 3Gb`

So if you really want csv formated data there's really nothing you can do about that size ...